# Using logic operator in mutate dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, logical-operators

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
df = data.frame(animals = c("cat; dog; bird", "dog; bird", "bird"), sentences = c("the cat is brown; the dog is barking; the bird is green and blue", "the bird is yellow and blue", "the bird is blue"),year= c("2010","2012","2001"), stringsAsFactors = F)

df$year <-  as.numeric(df$year)

> df
         animals                                                        sentences year
1       cat; dog                bird the cat is brown; the bird is green and blue 2010
2      dog; bird                    the dog is black; the bird is yellow and blue 2012
3           bird                                                 the bird is blue 2001
```

I would like to get the sum of animals inside the column sentences from the previous 5 years including the same year.

**Edit**

For example: in row2 the **animals** dog and bird, are repeated 3 times in the **sentences** column in the previous 5 years (including the same year) = year 2012: the **dog** is black; the **bird** is yellow and blue, and year 2010: the **bird** is green and blue, for a total of SUM = 3.

**Desired Outcome**

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  animals        sentences                                                         year   SUM
  <chr>          <chr>                                                            <dbl> <int>
1 cat; dog; bird the cat is brown; the bird is green and blue                      2010     2
2 dog; bird      the dog is black; the bird is yellow and blue                     2012     3
3 bird           the bird is blue                                                  2001     1
```

**Solution**

I have used the following code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54277205/search-for-multiple-values-in-a-column-in-r) and added a logical operator: 
 `animals[(year>=year-5) & (year<=year)]`, but it does not give me my desired output. What am I doing wrong?

```
string <- unlist(str_split(df$sentences, ";"))

   df %>% rowwise %>%
      mutate(SUM = str_split(animals[(year>=year-5) & (year<=year)], "; ", simplify = T) %>%
               map( ~ str_count(string, .)) %>%
               unlist %>% sum)
```

Any help would be much appreciated :) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(SUM = sapply(strsplit(animals, "; "), length),
         SUM = sapply(year, function(x) sum(SUM[between(year, x - 5 + 1, x)])))
```

This is the output:

```
         animals                                                        sentences year SUM
1 cat; dog; bird the cat is brown; the dog is barking; the bird is green and blue 2010   3
2      dog; bird                    the dog is black; the bird is yellow and blue 2018   2
3           bird                                                 the bird is blue 2001   1
```

Of course in `2010` it doesn't correspond to your desired output as you haven't provided the data for before.

Comment: Why did you use +1 in `between(year, x - 5 + 1, x)`?

Comment: Because if you want a 5-year period, and let's say you want it for 2015, the period starts at 2015 - 5 + 1 = 2011, and not 2015 - 5 = 2010. Of course you could just say `- 4`, but that's a way of keeping it transparent what is the window - so you always know which number to manipulate (e.g. for a 3-year period you just replace 5 with 3, etc.)

Comment: Thank you for this, there is only one last problem, I have to look for the animals names in the sentences column using `string <- unlist(str_split(df$sentences, ";"))` . Is there a way to include this in your solution above? (see the edit to my origin code above for clarification)

Comment: Not really sure what would be the desired output, best start another topic or modify this one as I don't see the direct link

Comment: thank you, I edited the question and added an example to clarify the desire output.

Comment: Hm, I've tried to understand but am not sure. For clarity I think it's best if you put this in another question or completely reframe your current one. For instance, I don't see where the `dog` appears twice, etc. You need to have a correct input and a clear desired output - what should happen with `string` when unlisted, what kind of output you expect? Etc..

Comment: I am not trying to count the number of animals in the **animals** column, I want to count the animals (from the animals column) that appear the **sentences** column in the past five years. I have already asked this question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54277205/search-for-multiple-values-in-a-column-in-r). In row 2, the SUM = 3 because bird appears twice, once in 2010 and once in 2012, whereas dog only once in 2012, in the **sentences** column. Thank you for helping me. :)

Comment: Not sure why it is asked again then, unfortunately will not have time to delve more into that now, perhaps someone else will pick it up